# Why is the BigQuery sink connector giving these errors?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying very hard to understand why the BigQuery sink connector v2.5 from Confluent is giving the following errors and not giving a good explanation of what is happening:

```
Caused by: Broken pipe
 at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.UpsertDeleteBigQueryWriter.attemptTableCreate(UpsertDeleteBigQueryWriter.java:92)
 at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.performWriteRequest(AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.java:105)
 at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.BigQueryWriter.writeRows(BigQueryWriter.java:116)
 at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.TableWriter.run(TableWriter.java:93)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Broken pipe
 at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:115)
 at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getTable(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:286)
 at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$18.call(BigQueryImpl.java:761)
 at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$18.call(BigQueryImpl.java:758)
 at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:103)
 at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
 at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
 at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getTable(BigQueryImpl.java:757)
 at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.SchemaManager.readTableSchema(SchemaManager.java:706)
 at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.SchemaManager.updateSchema(SchemaManager.java:268)
 at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.SchemaManager.createOrUpdateTable(SchemaManager.java:224)
 at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.UpsertDeleteBigQueryWriter.attemptTableCreate(UpsertDeleteBigQueryWriter.java:90)
 ... 6 more
```

It seems as if the connection with Google BigQuery is broken. Can I do anything about it? Currently I am using a region in the US and I am sending data from South Africa. Is it possible that the connection to the US is just congested or that the roundtrip is too long?  I would really appreciate any comments or help. I have been struggling with this for quite a while and I need to find a solution.